# LiteRollingSwitch throws me back from the settings page to the welcome page

Tags: flutter, dart

I used LiteRollingSwitch for a light-dark theme switch, it works but everytime I flip the switch it closes the settings page for no reason and gives me the welcome page then the dark/light theme appears.
I get nothing in the run and I am really stuck.

main.dart
`

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider(
          create: (_) => LoginService(),
        ),
        Provider(
          create: (_) => CategorySelectionService()
        )
      ],

      child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => ThemeProvider(),
        builder: (context, _) {
          final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
          return MaterialApp(
              themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,
              navigatorKey: Utils.mainAppNav,
              darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
              theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
              //ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              // home: settings(),
              initialRoute: '/',
              routes: {
                '/': (context) =>
                    SplashPage(goToPage: WelcomePage(), duration: 3),
                '/mainpage': (context) => MainPage(),
                '/selectedcategorypage': (context) => SelectedCategoryPage(),
                '/paginamaterii': (context) => Paginamaterii(),
                '/mappage': (context) => MapPage(),
                '/onboardingpage': (context) => OnBoardingPage(),
                '/gamespage' : (context) => GamesPage(),
                '/favoritespage' : (context) => Favoritspage(),
                '/settingspage' : (context) => settings()
              }
          );
        }
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

`

The switch (ChangeThemeButton.dart)
`

```
class ChangeThemeButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChangeThemeButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChangeThemeButton> createState() => _ChangeThemeButtonState();
}

class _ChangeThemeButtonState extends State<ChangeThemeButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: themeProvider.isDarkMode ? Colors.grey.shade800 : Colors.grey.shade200,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
            child: Text('Light-Dark Theme',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.scale(
            scale: 0.8,
            child: LiteRollingSwitch(
              value: themeProvider.isDarkMode,
              textOn: 'On',
              textOff: 'Off',
              textOffColor: Colors.white,
              textOnColor: Colors.white,
              colorOn: Colors.grey.shade900,
              colorOff: Colors.grey,
              iconOn: Icons.nightlight_round,
              iconOff: Icons.sunny,
              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1),
              onTap: () {},
              onDoubleTap: () {},
              onSwipe: () {},
              onChanged: (value) {
                final provider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
                provider.toggleTheme(value);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`settings.dart`

```
class settings extends StatefulWidget {
  const settings({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<settings> createState() => _settingsState();
}

class _settingsState extends State<settings> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MainAppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 10, left: 10),
          child: ChangeThemeButton()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

I tried to change the settings page and the switch button from StatelessWidget to StatefulWidget

Comment: you rebuild entire app with navigation stack like that (ChangeNotifierProvider does), 2 ways - you scope your state settings above CNP (not really how it has to be done but thats just to understand the scope) or use consumer widgets like here - https://levelup.gitconnected.com/theme-switcher-with-provider-f84f947b9044